# Make "object" delete at "distance", when "created"? C# programming

Tags: c#

I'm a complete newb, working on a 2D RTS game. So far I've created an object "infantry" and can make it shoot a "bullet" in specified direction, and can only find the code to delete bullet once outside the room. I want the bullet to delete at a relative distance of 300pixels from the infantry. And need the code to be very clean, hence there will be a lot of bullets eventually. My question is: Should I make a rectangle around the infantry, to specify range and line of sight, and when bullet collides with range = delete? or Should the bullet class say "once created + distance traveled = 300 pixels = delete"?... Any code, or hints you can offer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I would strongly suggest that if you're really a complete newbie, you should start with something simpler than an RTS game.

Comment: I have done simpler games, and watched many tutorials, but none offer the understanding of the problem i'm having. We all have been in this position at one point and time, of being stuck somewhere. And someone's help, was always better than someone's doubt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple method:

- Store the origin point, where the projectile is created (at the gun barrel)
- Each frame, use the distance formula to find out whether the projectile has exceeded the travel radius.
- You can avoid the `Math.Sqrt` call in the distance formula, by comparing to the square of the radius.

  ```
  var dx = xbullet - xorigin;
  var dy = ybullet - yorigin;
  if (dx*dx + dy*dy > range*range) delete bullet
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I think your second suggestion is better. If you make a box or check the distance to the soldier, then the bullet could travel longer if the soldier run after the bullet (if the bullet is not instant-travel, that is).